# Variable of Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

Rather than stumble through it (with my limited understanding), please explain what is happening to (and the use of) the `head` var in the following 3 lines of code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var head = $("thead#tHead1").clone().removeAttr("class");
  $(head).find("#hRow2").remove();
  head = $(head).wrap("<thead>").parent().html();
```

**Edit** 
What is the significance of using `$(head)` on the 2nd line of code, after setting `head =` on the 1st and then assigning head to another value?

See answers for what I learned.

Comment: Yes. It will refer to the cloned head element in the 2nd line. Same for `$(head)` in 3rd line.

Comment: @nhahtdh Please check edit. The 'usage' question wasn't clear.

Comment: That's some bad code. `<thead>` elements don't belong within other `<thead>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Find an element, make a copy of it, and remove it's class
var head = $("thead#tHead1").clone().removeAttr("class");

// Within the cloned element (not on the DOM yet),
// Find an element within and then remove that found element.
$(head).find("#hRow2").remove();

// Wrap the cloned element in another element, giving it a parent.
// Traverse to that parent and return it's html content
head = $(head).wrap("<thead>").parent().html();
```

Note the `$(head)` shouldn't be needed here.  That can simply be `head` instead. You don't need to convert the element to a jQuery wrapped object because it should already be one.

---

Also, this is terrible code.  It's a kludgy hack on the DOM to do whatever it is supposed to.  INstead you should using a templating engine of some kind to generate fresh DOM fragments as needed based on some input data.

Comment: Alex, Would you find the bottom 2 lines of code (edited) as a correct way to write them?

Comment: That would marginally improve the code, yes.  But honestly I think should take a step back and re-evaluate the approach here.  But that's an entirely different question.

Comment: To your 'kludgy hack' suggestion. Accepted. I am trying to compensate for tables in browsers - not handling a page break 'when going to print'. And, without reloading the page. Got a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'll walk you through the lines:

1. An opening `<script>` tag, which by the way doesn't need a `type` attribute.
2. Find the `<thead>` element with an id of `tHead1`, duplicate the element including child nodes, and remove the `class` attribute from the new element, then assign the new element to the `head` variable.
3. Remove the element with an id of `hRow2` that's inside the element we created earlier.
4. Wrap the element we created earlier in a `thead` element, and reassign the `head` variable to equal the innerHTML of that '' element.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments and further study,  I gathered that this could be better written as:

```
var head = $("#tHead1").clone().removeAttr("class");   // clean & clone the head  
head.find("#hRow2").remove();                          // remove 2nd row
head = head[0].outerHTML;                              // get 'only' the desired html
```

To answer my own question, (I'm not sure of the terminology) the last `head =` is necessary in this case, to not display `[object Object]`. Instead of an object, it assigns the desired HTML (header rows) to be used a few lines later in the code. `console.log(head)` revealed this lesson. I'm also not sure why rows 1 and 2 can't be chained, so this is as clean as I can make it.

The higher purpose of this exercise is to break a large table into separate (45 row) tables, before printing, having only 2 of 3 header rows visible on following pages and not contacting the server or reloading the page. My method for this is to add an end-of-page class to the nth row, accomplish the above and then appendTo() the new table & header after that row.